# Refresh Router React navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have router with conditional rendring.

```
    const {
        checkedSignIn,
        isSignedIn,

        redirectTo
    } = this.props.screenProps;

    const navigation = this.props.navigation;

    if (isSignedIn) {
        const obj = Object.assign({}, this.props, this.props.screenProps);
        return (
            <DashboardTabComponent
                 //navigation={navigation}
                //  screenProps={this.props.screenProps}
                screenProps={obj}
            />
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <HomeScreen
                 navigation={navigation}
                 screenProps={this.props.screenProps}
            />
        );
    }
```

And inside 'DashboardTabComponent' in one of the tab have sign out button when I press sign out button it should re-render this component so that it can show Home screen.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? Please clarify, your question is extremely unclear at the moment

Comment: try to migrate to React Router V4

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Iam using react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org. How can i migrate to v4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh in React Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088695/how-to-refresh-in-react-navigation)